# Multiple source from images javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, tampermonkey

I am trying to get the source of 3 images on a webpage using javascript.
Now.. the first image source I can get but the 2 others give me the Cannot read src of null error.

Here is my code:

```
var a = document.querySelector("#cimg1 > img").src;
var b = document.querySelector("#cimg2 > img").src;
var c = document.querySelector("#cimg3 > img").src;

alert(String(a+b+c));
```

HTML:

```html
<form name="mainf" onsubmit="javascript:dosub();return false;">
   <div align="center">
    <table>
     <tbody>
       <tr>
         <td>
           <div id="cimg1">
            <img width="35" height="55" src="images/capchs/6.png">
           </div>
         </td>
         <td>
           <div id="cimg2">
      <img width="35" height="55" src="images/capchs/1.png">
           </div>
         </td>
         <td>
           <div id="cimg3">
      <img width="35" height="55" src="images/capchs/9.png">
           </div>
         </td>
       </tr>
    </tbody>
   </table>
  </div>
</form>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your code is running well for me, check if there is any console error

Comment: userscript.html?id=b93dc5b0-9091-4e94-940c-918e8351bc1e:4 ERROR: Execution of script 'MrSebasAutoCaptcha' failed! Cannot read property 'src' of null

Comment: Can i maybe contact you through mail or discord ?

Comment: Code works on raw html but not when i try to run it on a website

Comment: Are you waiting until the DOM is ready before you query for the images?

Comment: How would I run my code after the DOM is ready?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check that the Dom content has loaded as @chazsolo has pointed out. You're looking for an image src before it exists on the page. If you're using jquery you must wrap your code in a function like so...

```
$(function(){
    //... put your code here....
});
```

if vanilla js then you can do something like...

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
    //... put your code here....  
});
```